# Jenkins on docker fails to run for a build script

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am using jenkins image to run on docker container. I have a modified version of the image as below:

```
USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y sudo
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm -v
USER jenkins
```

when I run the container based on this image it all goes fine. I can go into the container and do npm -v and it all works just fine. However, the build script on my jenkins which is simply as

```
echo 'starting build'
npm -v
```

fails with error npm not found.

Answer (score 1):

npm is not in the path of your jenkins' user.

You could get a shell on your container to figure out the npm path:

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER_NAME> bash
which npm
```

Then you could run it with a full path in the jenkins script, symlink it, add it to $PATH etc...